# How Do You Find AttributeID for Custom RTC Attributes?

Tags: rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz, oslc

If, for example, I have a custom attribute for my work tickets called "SuperAttributeValue", how do I figure out what to put in place of [attributeId] given the below statement from Jazz' [instructions](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/WorkItemAPIsForOSLCCM20#RTC_Work_Item_Vocabulary)? I've tried putting in "SuperAttributeValue" as the ID, and I've tried making up numbers, but neither results in any values of any kind. So how do I figure out what the real attributeId is?

If requiring code to get attribute IDs, I need C# specific code.

`"Custom attributes are exposed as: rtc_ext:[attributeId]"`

**Update:** I found if I set the parameter "oslc.properties" to "*" I get a LOT of the options in the return data. Still, I'm not seeing all the ones I know exists--only some of them. Not sure what * does if not a wildcard for everything. rtc_ext:* doesn't work to give me only rtc_ext attributes though. Any better options I can put there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, using * for oslc.properties when requesting a ticket may indeed be sufficient to get all the attributes in the return. The names of the attributes I see in RTC are different from what I expect which makes it rather cryptic. Intead of SuperAttributeValue which I would see in RTC, it might come across as some.dumb.really.long.thing.amazing.attribute and instead of a value of 150 which I might expect, it might not have a value at all, but a "resource" attribute for the attribute. The resource will be like https://host.com:9943/ccm/some.dumb.long.enum.I125 and if you go to that resource, you will see it maps to 150. Not as straight-forward as I'd have hoped.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing same difficulties as you mentioned. Quick question, when you use the dotted attributeId in oslc.select did you get any errors? I'm using elmclient python library and it seems the dotted attributeId is not valid syntactically.

Comment: @Larcis it's been quite a while since I did anything with this so I don't recall much, but maybe you need to use %2E for the periods?